# How to understand the Fourier transform of a stationary random function?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fourier-transform, stochastic-processes, turbulence

A stationary random function like $v(t;w)$ is not periodic and not squared integrable, why we can do a Fourier transform to it, which is a very common process to analyze turbulence. How will a mathematician to do a Fourier Transform to a stationary random function？

Comment: To extract the information. Not all points in field has same velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stationary random function is a type of mathematical function that is characterized by its statistical properties, rather than its specific form or shape. A stationary random function is one that has the property that its statistical properties, such as its mean and variance, do not change over time.

One common example of a stationary random function is the velocity of a fluid flow, such as a turbulent flow. This type of function is not periodic and is not squared integrable, which means that it does not satisfy the usual conditions for performing a Fourier transform.

However, despite this, it is still possible to perform a Fourier transform on a stationary random function, such as the velocity of a turbulent flow. This can be done using a specialized type of Fourier transform known as the Wiener-Khinchin theorem, which is a generalization of the classical Fourier transform that is specifically designed for dealing with stationary random functions.

The Wiener-Khinchin theorem allows for the Fourier transform of a stationary random function to be computed in terms of its autocorrelation function, which is a measure of how the function is correlated with itself over time. This allows for the spectral properties of the stationary random function to be analyzed, which can be useful for understanding the statistical properties of the function and for studying phenomena such as turbulence.

Comment: i can accept to do a Fourier transform to autocorrelation function, but sometimes i see some textbooks do Fourier transform or Fourier series directly to, for example, velocity field. why can do that?

Comment: It is not possible to directly perform a Fourier transform on a vector field, as the Fourier transform is a mathematical operation that is defined only for functions of a single variable, not for vector-valued functions. In order to apply the Fourier transform to a vector field, it is necessary to first express the field in terms of its individual components (i.e. the x, y, and z components), and then apply the Fourier transform to each component separately. This will result in a transformed vector field that can be analyzed using the tools of Fourier analysis.

Comment: i didn't mean i can accept scalar cannot accept vector previously. i can accept autocorrelation function because it tend to zero when -> ∞, it is absolutely integrable. but a fluctuating velocity field in turbulence context is not tend to zero when -> ∞, it isn't absolutely integrable in entire axis.